# Error in flutter: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, null, flutter-textformfield

I am new to flutter world

I tried to direct the `TextFormField in this way, and this error in the title appeared

I want to use  Directionality `textDirection: TextDirection.rtl`,

but this what happened

```
Widget _buildName() {
    Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'الاسم', hintText: 'أدخل اسمك'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'يجب أن لا يكون الحقل فارغًا';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String? value) {
        _name = value;
      },
    ));
  }
```

Comment: I do not know how to add the code like you guys

Comment: The code was working like this

Comment: Widget _buildName() {
      return TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'الاسم', hintText: 'أدخل اسمك'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'يجب أن لا يكون الحقل فارغًا';
        }
        return 'null';
      },
      onSaved: (String? value) {
        _name = value;
      },
    );
  }

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: I did, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting the error because you are not returning anything. add `return` keyword before Directionality() and it should work:

```html
Widget _buildName() {
return  Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'الاسم', hintText: 'أدخل اسمك'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'يجب أن لا يكون الحقل فارغًا';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (String? value) {
        _name = value;
      },
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Widget _buildName() {
    Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'الاسم', hintText: 'أدخل اسمك'),
      maxLength: 10,
      validator: (String? value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'يجب أن لا يكون الحقل فارغًا';
        }
        return '';///here
      },
      onSaved: (String? value) {
        _name = value;
      },
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but does not work